# Switches in Tableviews

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswitch

I have the following custom `UITableViewCell`:

[image]

I want my view controller to be notified when somebody flips a cell's switch in order to update my model. I've tried using the table view's delegate methods (`didSelect`, `didFinishEditing`, `didHighlight`, etc.) but none of them are called upon this action. Is there any way to do what I want to do? Somebody please help.

Comment: you could do it via notification. Send a notification from your custom cell. Or your can do it with `addAction(...)` for the switch controls. Oh and your title doesn't describe what you want to do (sliders vs switch ;) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

actually your UISwitch has added to `accessoryView` of `UITableViewCell`, so do like on `cellforRowAtIndex`

```
var switchView = UISwitch(frame: CGRect.zero)
aCell.accessoryView = switchView
lightSwitch.tag = indexPath.row
switchView.setOn(false, animated: false)
switchView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchChanged(_:), for: .valueChanged)
```

and get the action of `UISwitch` as

```
func switchChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {

    print("which switch is \(sender.tag)")
    print("The switch is \(sender?.on ? "ON" : "OFF")")
}
```

Comment: But if you have more than one switch, can you get wich switch was toggle with this method?

Comment: @Adarkas2302 - simple, assign the tag for switch

Answer (score 0):

To update your model when somebody flips a cell's switch you need:

1. Assign cell's `@IBAction func onSwitched(_ sender: UISwitch)` as `UISwitch Value Changed` listener as shown on this screenshot

   [image]
2. Attach color model to cell

   `cell.myColorModel = myColorModels[indexPath.row]`
3. In `@IBAction func onSwitched(_ sender: UISwitch)` simply change `selected` property in model

   `@IBAction func onSwitched(_ sender: UISwitch) {
       myColorModel.selected = sender.isOn
   }`

**FULL SOURCE CODE**

```
class MyColorModel {  

    var title: String!
    var color: UIColor!
    var selected: Bool = false

    init(title: String, color: UIColor) {
        self.title = title
        self.color = color
    }
}

class MyColorCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var colorTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var colorImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var colorSwitch: UISwitch!

    var myColorModel: MyColorModel! {
        didSet {
            colorTitle.text = myColorModel.title
            colorImage.backgroundColor = myColorModel.color
            colorSwitch.isOn = myColorModel.selected
        }
    }

    @IBAction func onSwitched(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        myColorModel.selected = sender.isOn
    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    fileprivate var myColorModels = [MyColorModel(title: "Red", color: UIColor.red),
                                 MyColorModel(title: "Green", color: UIColor.green),
                                 MyColorModel(title: "Blue", color: UIColor.blue)]


    @IBAction func onColorsCheck(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        for myColorModel in myColorModels {
            print("color \(myColorModel.title) \((myColorModel.selected) ? "is checked":"is not checked")")
        }
    }

    // MARK: - UITableView datasource & delegate

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myColorModels.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyColorCell") as! MyColorCell

        cell.myColorModel = myColorModels[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense except for the fact that I want the last IBAction method to be automated. Is this possible?

Comment: @NikhilSridhar What do you mean for '...last IBAction method to be automated...'? What goal are you trying to achieve by that approach with 'automated IBAction method'?

Share the problem you want to solve then we will try to find solution for that.